# Elemento repetido dentro de matriz - Pascal

Tags: matriz, pascal

Estou tentando, à um bom tempo, produzir um código que identifique e relate ao usuário se existem elementos repetidos em uma matriz 5x5, composta por números aleatórios, no pascal. Já tentei pesquisar a matriz usando uma, ou duas, variáveis e também com uma matriz inteira para pesquisa, mas não deu certo. 
Ouvi falar, de algumas pessoas, que não é necessário um código muito grande, e nem muito complexo para a tarefa. Assim meu desespero aumenta.

Pergunto se alguém tem alguma solução para o problema

Link PasteBin para tentativa mal sucedida (e mais viajada)-  https://pastebin.com/uzPLACXe

Código:

```
program Exercicio5;
var
  Matr, same: array [1..5, 1..5] of real;
  lin, col, linPesq, ColPesq:integer;
  repete: boolean;

begin
  randomize;
  for lin:= 1 to 5 do
    begin
    writeln;
    for col:= 1 to 5 do
      begin
        Matr[lin, col]:= random (1000);
        same[lin,col]:= Matr[lin,col];
        write(Matr[lin, col]:0:2, ' | ');
        end;
    end;
  for LinPesq:= 1 to 5 do
      begin
        for ColPesq:= 1 to 5 do
          begin
            for lin:= 1 to 5 do
              begin
                for col:= 1 to 5 do
                  begin

                    if same[LinPesq,ColPesq] = Matr[lin, col] then
                        begin
                          if lin and col and LinPesq and ColPesq <> 1 then
                            begin
                        repete := true;
                        break;
                              end;
                          end;
                    end;
                  end;
                    end;
                end;
  writeln;
  writeln;
  if repete = true then
    writeln('Ha elementos repetidos na matriz')
      else
        writeln('Nao ha elementos repetidos na matriz');
  readln;

end.
```

Comment: olá, coloque seu código aqui para melhorar a visualização

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá

Seu caminho está correto na análise. Creio que o único descuido foi em relação a comparação que você estava fazendo através de uma segunda matriz, quando na verdade o que interessa é uma comparação elemento a elemento no caso.

Portanto, no código a seguir o que faço é andar pelos elementos da matriz, guardar o valor do elemento em uma variável (nVal) que a seguir vai comparar com todos os outros elementos da matriz (linhas de 1 a 5) e (colunas de 1 a 5), buscando pelo mesmo valor, mas, analisando ainda se linha ou coluna é diferente da que está sendo consultada.

No caso, este trecho de código serve para verificar se trata-se da própria linha e coluna que está em análise ou se de fato trata-se de outro elemento:

```
( ( lin <> LinPesq ) or ( col <> ColPesq ) )
```

Coloquei em um looping somente para facilitar na hora de analisar o código

```
nTestes:= 10;
for i:= 1 to nTestes do
   (...)
end;
```

Enfim, o código final ficou desta forma:

```
program elemento_repetido;
var
    Matr: array [1..5, 1..5] of real;
    i, nTestes, lin, col, linPesq, ColPesq:integer;
    repete: boolean;
    nRepetido, nVal: real;
begin
    nTestes:= 10;
    for i:= 1 to nTestes do
    begin
        writeln('Teste #', i );
        repete:= false;
        randomize;
        for lin:= 1 to 5 do
        begin
            writeln;
            for col:= 1 to 5 do
            begin
                Matr[lin, col]:= random (1000);
                write(Matr[lin, col]:0:2, ' | ');
            end;
        end;
        for LinPesq:= 1 to 5 do
        begin
            for ColPesq:= 1 to 5 do
            begin
                nVal:= Matr[LinPesq,ColPesq];
                for lin:= 1 to 5 do
                begin
                    for col:= 1 to 5 do
                    begin
                        if ( nVal = Matr[lin,col] ) and 
                           ( ( lin <> LinPesq ) or ( col <> ColPesq ) ) then
                        begin
                            nRepetido:= nVal;
                            repete:= true;
                            break;
                        end;
                    end;
                end;
            end;
        end;
        writeln;
        writeln;
        if repete then
            writeln('Há elementos repetidos na matriz: ', nRepetido:6:2 )
        else
            writeln('Nao há elementos repetidos na matriz');
        readln;
    end;
end.
```

Comment: Muito obrigado por responder. Código muito bem feitinho :)

Comment: De nada, disponha!